# This set of matrices is open

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

I'm trying to prove that the set of the matrices whose eigenvalues have non-zero real part is an open subset of $M^n$, the set of square matrices with order $n$ which is identify with $\mathbb R^{n^2}$.

I don't know even how to begin, this question is really different to me, I don't how to use these topological concepts in relation with the eigenvalues of matrices.

I really need help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a direct consequence of the following three facts:

1. The inverse image of an open set under a continuous function is open.
2. $(\mathbb{C}\setminus i\mathbb{R})^n$ is open.
3. **The eigenvalues of a real or complex matrix are continuous functions of the matrix entries.** See, e.g. James M. Ortega, *Numerical Analysis: A Second Course*, [p.45, Theorem 3.1.2](http://books.google.com/books?id=_NyUbOj5iwQC&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=Numerical%20Analysis%3a%20A%20Second%20Course%20continuity%20of%20eigenvalues&source=bl&ots=RkUH2YiV00&sig=y2vggDN3j6f0IrTz5By_GVA0VeM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sJfuUcGsGO6RiQel8YCYAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Numerical%20Analysis%3a%20A%20Second%20Course%20continuity%20of%20eigenvalues&f=false). Since coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of a matrix are polynomials in the matrix entries, and eigenvalues are roots of the characteristic polynomial, it suffices to prove that the roots of a generic polynomial $p(z)$ over $\mathbb{C}$ are continuous functions of the coefficients of $p$. And this is exactly what the proof in Ortega infers. As noted by Ted Shifrin in another answer here, this can be proved easily with [Rouché's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem).

Comment: Why $i\mathbb R$ is closed?

Comment: @user42912 A set is closed if it contains all its limit points. Now, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}iy_n=z$ for some sequence $(iy_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset i\mathbb{R}$, do you see that $z\in i\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: it's easy, we just have to see $\mathbb C$ as $\mathbb R^2$, then $\lim(0,y_n)=(0,\lim y_n)\in i\mathbb R$. Am I right?

Answer (score 8):

As you can prove, for example with Rouché's Theorem, the roots of a complex polynomial vary continuously with the coefficients.

To state this more precisely: Suppose $f(z) = z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\dots+a_0$ has roots $w_1,\dots,w_r$. Then, given $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ so that whenever $|b_j-a_j|<\delta$ for $j=0,\dots,n-1$, the roots of $g(z)=z^n+b_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\dots+b_0$ are all contained in $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^r B(w_k,\varepsilon)$.

Comment: where can I find such theorems? do you have some resources?

Comment: Sadly, I don't know a place this is proved. But I've given it as an exercise numerous times. Do you know Rouché's Theorem from complex analysis?

Comment: no I don't know :(

Comment: What mathematics do you know? If you have not studied some complex analysis or winding numbers in topology, you won't be able to figure out a proof and will just need to take this statement as a fact. You might want to look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem for starters.

Answer (score 4):

Pick a norm (preferrably the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty$) and write down, what 
$$B_\epsilon(M) := \{A \in M^n | \Vert M-A \Vert < \epsilon\}$$
looks like. Then prove that every matrix in $O := \{ A\in M^n | \Re(\lambda) \neq 0 \ \forall \lambda \in \sigma(A)\}$ has an $\epsilon > 0$ with
$$B_\epsilon(M) \subset O$$
For that you can use theorems about the bevahiour of eigenvalues under small disturbances.

Comment: I don't know these theorems, that's my problem.

Comment: Maybe look into references for numerical mathematics (eigenvalue algorithms) these books usually contain some theorems about this; unfortunately I don't have any at hand right now and a simple google search didn't yield anything good for me.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another approach: show that the complement is closed. So, given a convergent sequence $M_1,M_2,\dots\to M$ of matrices (in some metric equivalent to the usual metric on $\mathbb R^{n^2}$) which each have an eigenvalue whose real part is zero, we want to show that $M$ has an eigenvalue whose real part is zero.

There are eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and eigenvectors $v_i$ such that $\mathrm{Re}(\lambda_i)=0$ and $M_iv_i=\lambda_iv_i$ for all $i$; furthermore we can normalise so that $\|v_i\|=1$ in the $L_2$ norm. So $\lambda_i=\langle M_iv_i,v_i\rangle$ where $\langle x,y\rangle$ denotes the usual Hermitian inner product ($\sum_k x_k\overline{y_k}$). Because the set of unit vectors is compact, passing to a subsequence if necessary, we may assume that $v_i$ converges to some unit vector $v$. The vectors $M_iv_i= \langle M_iv_i,v_i\rangle v_i$ then converge to $\langle Mv,v\rangle v$ by continuity of multiplication, and the real part of $\langle Mv,v\rangle$ is clearly zero.

Comment: Why the set of unit vectors is compact?

Comment: It's closed (it's the preimage of the closed set $\{1\}$ under the norm map) and bounded as a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, so [the Heine-Borel theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem) applies.

Comment: I didn't understand the bounded part, every subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is bounded?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in other answers, the meat of this is to show that the eigenvalues of a complex matrix depend continuously on the matrix coefficients.  Note that since the eigenvalues are not naturally ordered and can come with multiplicities, one should make precise exactly what above statement means, and there may be more than one reasonable interpretation.  I will take it to mean: for all $M = (m_{ij}) \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that if $M' = (m_{ij}') \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is such that $|m_{ij}-m_{ij}'| < \delta$ for all $1 \leq i,j \leq n$, then for every eigenvalue $\alpha$ of $M$, there is an eigenvalue $\alpha'$ of $M'$ with $|\alpha-\alpha'| < \epsilon$, and for every eigenvalue $\alpha'$ of $M'$, there is an eigenvalue $\alpha$ of $M$ with $|\alpha-\alpha'| < \epsilon$.

(Then to answer the question, suppose $M$ has an eigenvalue $\alpha$ with nonzero real part $x$, and take $\epsilon = x$.)

It is clear that the *coefficients* of the characterstic polynomial of $M$ depend continuously on the entries of $M$: indeed, they are polynomial functions in $M$.  So really we need to show:

> The roots of a complex polynomial $f = a_nt^n + \ldots + a_1t + a_0$ depend continuously on the coefficients: for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that: if $g = b_n t^n + \ldots + b_1t + b_0$ is such that $|a_i-b_i| < \delta$ for all $0 \leq i \leq n$, then every root of $g$ is within $\epsilon$ of some root of $f$ and vice versa.

I posed this -- with $\mathbb{C}$ replaced by any algebraically closed **normed field** -- as a problem in a graduate number theory course I taught several years ago.  It was solved by Mr. David Krumm (now Dr. David Krumm).  I seem to recall that he solved it several times over (with some variant on the statement) but settled on an approach which is simple and extremely elementary.  In particular, in contrast to a statement made in another answer here, one certainly does not need Rouche's Theorem or winding number considerations (which are not available anyway in an arbitrary normed field).  His solution was so nice that I got him to write it up: it is available [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Math8410Ex3.17David.pdf).

(Note that I asked a couple of related preliminary questions which he solved on page 1.  For this question you can start reading on page 2.  There are only two pages!)

Comment: Interesting indeed. Thanks. +1

Comment: Nice. But this, to me, an example where an "elementary proof" gives less insight. But I'm glad to know it can be done :)

Comment: @Ted: if you have to use more technology to prove a less general statement, then I have to wonder how much insight your technology is really giving you.  Of course insight is in the eye of the beholder: to me Artin's proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra which uses only that every odd-degree real polynomial has a root and that every quadratic equation over $\mathbb{R}(\sqrt{-1})$ has a solution is much more insightful than the proof using Liouville's Theorem...

Comment: @Pete, it's not that surprising our tastes differ :) But now you have me curious. Is the result false over a non-ordered fiekd like $\mathbb Q_p$? P.S. I too like Artin's proof — for a graduate class :)

Comment: @Ted: I'm not sure exactly what you're referring to, but if it's whether $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{-1})$ is algebraically closed: no way.  The algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ has infinite degree over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, as one can see most easily by observing that the polynomials $t^n-p$ are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for all $p$ (Gauss's Lemma + Eisenstein Criterion).

Comment: Further, if $K$ is any field for which $\overline{K}/K$ is a proper, finite degree extension, then $K$ admits a unique ordering and $K(\sqrt{-1})$ is algebraically closed.  See $\S$ 16.4 of http://math.uga.edu/~pete/FieldTheory.pdf.

Comment: @Pete:  Sorry not to have clarified, I meant the result about roots of a polynomial varying continuously. David's proof definitely hinged on an ordering, not just a metric.

Comment: @Ted: sorry, I was ranting (all in good fun...) and missed your last comment.  Actually you're mistaken: David's proof does not use any ordering on the field, but only that the field has a norm (which induces a metric).  The inequalities are applied only to $|x|$, never to $x$.  (The terminology "$\beta$ is within $\epsilon$ of $\alpha$" means $|\alpha-\beta| < \epsilon$.)

Comment: @Pete: The hypothesis was $K$ an ordered field, and I thought he took a min of a bunch of things?

Comment: @Ted: Please look again.  If you're still not satisfied, feel free to contact me in "real life".